# How to use htslib/samtools to transform SAM/BAM reads?

Tags: bioinformatics, samtools, bam

I'm using the `htslib` library for reading SAM/BAM files, it works perfectly. I can also write the alignments back to a new SAM/BAM file.

For example, the following code prints the DNA sequence of an alignment:

```
    bam1_t *b = ...;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < b->core.l_qseq; ++i) {
        printf("%c", seq_nt16_str[bam_seqi(bam_get_seq(b),i)]);
    }
```

**Question**: How do I change the query sequence? Say, change the first letter to 'T'? `bam_get_seq` returns the sequence of a read, but there is no `bam_set_seq` function? Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
 bam_set_seq(b, 'TTTT') # My new DNA sequence
```

If I can figure out how to do the update, I know how to write the information to a new SAM/BAM file.

Comment: Why not just use Samtools and linux to create a text file of your alignment and then in perl/python manipulate the sequence as a string?

Comment: Samtools seems to be focused on collecting stats/viewing existing data in various ways, etc., but not on facilitating arbitrary changes to underlying data?

Comment: @flyingfinger I don't think it's possible.